# Create markdown style ` (backtick) shortcode in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, markdown, shortcode

I want to create markdown style backtick shortcode...

...that replaces backtick pairs with a `<span class="inline_code"></span>` pair, but did not found how to achieve this without `[]` signs and without `[/]` closing tag. Same goes for `**` to `<strong></strong>`.

Can you provide some links / examples for such a shortcode pattern? I'm happy with some other (non-shortcode) solitions as well if there is no other way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By adding such **content filters** (to `functions.php` or below):

```
function add_markdown_tiny($content)
{
    $patterns = array
    (
        '/`([^\*]+)`/',
        '/\*\*([^\*]+)\*\*/'
    );

    $replacements = array
    (
        '<code>$1</code>',
        '<strong>$1</strong>'
    );

    $replaced = preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $content);
    return $replaced;
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'add_markdown_tiny', 10);
```